# How to specify --device option for Docker run command?

Tags: docker, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-edge

I'm testing out the new Azure IoT Edge V2. I need to run the Docker image deployed to the edge device with the --device option like this (to access a serial port):

```
$ docker run --device=/dev/serial/by-id/usb-ELT_SENSOR_EK100_V1.0_SN000001-if00-port0 olavt.azurecr.io/testco2sensor-arm32
```

How do I specify the `--device` option when creating the new deployment from the Azure portal?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In theory you can specify anything documented in the docker api container create options stated here https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.30/#operation/ContainerCreate

In the device case you could (I never tried it that way) specify in the `createOptions`:

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Devices": [
      {
        "PathOnHost": "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-ELT_SENSOR_EK100_V1.0_SN000001-if00-port0",
        "PathInContainer": "/dev/serial/by-id/usb-ELT_SENSOR_EK100_V1.0_SN000001-if00-port0",
        "CgroupPermissions": "rwm"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What works for sure it to privilege the container completely opening up everything on the hardware side. To do this you just use the `Privileged` parameter. Note there is only one d in Privileged.

```
{
  "HostConfig": {
    "Privileged": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error for the device: "500 - One or more errors occurred. (Docker API responded with status code=InternalServerError, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: device access at 8 field cannot be empty: unknown"})". Is there a log with more details?

Comment: I assume that is running on raspbian, right? What version of docker are you running?

Comment: I just tried it today and realized that the Azure Portal setting the createOptions is flaky, somehow it doesn't store the values you specify when setting modules. As a workaround (as this is still preview) I suggest that you use a deployment script for updating the deployment manifest. Here is a [github repository](https://github.com/jonbgallant/azure-iot-edge-config) you can use for that matter. That should fix the problem

Comment: Your original answer is partly correct. If you add "CgroupPermissions": "rwm" to the JSON it works.